# Getting the result of a servlet in a browser

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This question might have been asked quite a few times and might have been answered as well.I have searched for quite some time for the answer and havent found it yet.
Lets start from the begining .

I have jdk 8 installed on my c: drive in program files in java folder
C:\Program Files\java\

I extracted the installed apache tomcat in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\

i have setup a CATALINA_HOME variable pointing to apache directory and a java home variable pointing to jdk 8 directory as entioned above.
Path is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin; 
and classpath is set to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\lib\servlet-api.jar
i ran tomcat buy going to command promt and catalina_home/lib/statup.bat and it ran successfully and i could see the server's homepage when i typed the url localhost:8080
now i have setup folders in the catalina_home as follows
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.0.5\webapps\ch03\WEB-INF\classes\com\wrox\projsp\ch03\myfirstwebapp (this was mentioned in a book of wrox publications from which i was trying to read)in the "myfirstwebapp" folder i created a MyFirstServlet.java file which has the following code

```
    package com.wrox.projsp.ch03.myfirstwebapp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

public class MyFirstServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("this is my first servlet");    
    }
}
```

After that i compiled the .java file by typing in the command promt "javac MyFirstServlet.java" which created a MyFirstServlet.class file in the same folder.But When i try to access it from the browser by typing

```
http://localhost:8080/ch03/servlet/com.wrox.projsp.ch03.MyFirstServlet
```

it gives an error saying " The requested resource is not available." why is that so?
I think i have done all the necessary steps .What is the reason for it?And apologies in advance if i have miss communicated .My writing skills are poor . And please dont down grade  this post as i have put a lot of effort in it and only posted this question after i have no other options left .Thanks in advance

```
type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class com.wrox.projsp.ch03.MyFirstServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
Exception:

    javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.wrox.projsp.ch03.MyFirstServlet
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2451)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2440)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    root cause

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.wrox.projsp.ch03.MyFirstServlet
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1328)
        org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1175)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1017)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2451)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2440)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Why is no body answering my question?

Answer (score 0):

Your not typing the write url, your servlet can be accessed at: `http://localhost:8080/ch03/MyFirstServlet`

Comment: I have put the code in text file and it is not being accessed by the url you mentioned

Comment: does it gives the same error? The Tomcat server is running? try http://localhost:8080/ch03/servlet/MyFirstServlet.

Comment: still not running and yes giving the same error .And yes the server is running ,it is showing http status 404.I think the problem is with the url mapping .I dont understand I have done everyting right .My server is also running .Why is this a problem.

Comment: Try this one: http://localhost:8080/ch03/com.wrox.projsp.ch03.MyFirstServlet I've never used Tomcat didn't know you needed to put the package.

Comment: I think it wont work. Here's another tutorial http://www.nogoodatcoding.com/howto/deploy-a-servlet-on-tomcat

Comment: i was rechecking some thing related to CATALINA_HOME variable and i have noticed that in the CATALINA_HOME directory there is no folder name "common" there is only a "lib" folder which has a servlet-api.jar file ? is that a problem ?

Comment: ther is no web.xml file .The book i was reading from has not mentioned to use any xml file although it mentioned about the file when describing the details of the apache tomcat server but in the section "The first servlet" it didnt mention anything to do with a xml file

Comment: i have already read the link you gave me :D . I have done everything right except the xml file part .Is it the reason ? because nothing is mentioned in the book i have reading from "Professional JSP 2nd edition" it has many different authors .Its a book by wrox publishers

Comment: I dont have a folder named "common " in the CATALINA_HOME path .The tutorial you mentioned says it should be  there .I have downloaded it from apache.org/tomcat.Why so ?

Comment: The CATALINA_HOME/common/lib is not a problem since you are using another version. It seems that they changed it to /lib

Comment: It seems that the book your following is using a different version of tomcat server (since tomcat 8 and jdk8 are very recent). So you have two options, or you find another tutorial about how to setup the tomcat 8. Or you install an older tomcat version (which should be more stable and have more support). Personally I would install a older version. In last case you can use another application server like JBOSS, Glassfish.

Comment: I have also added an xml file according to the tutorial you mentinoned and have made the required changes and still i am unable to access it.And no one else except you seems to care :(

Comment: The problem is that the tomcat version it refers to is not compatible with the latest version of java so i have to use this version of tomcat ,I tried tomcat v6 aswell but it didnt help either .I think i am doomed

Comment: yes jdk8 is very recent, try to install an older tomcat version and an older java version like 7. Unless you really want to use java 8 in this case you can try this tutorial https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/setup.html from tomcat

Comment: I think tomcat 8 is a beta version?

Comment: I guess i should use jdk 7 with tomcat 7 .

Answer (score 0):

You need a mapping from the url to the servlet. Try adding the `@WebServlet` annotation to the class:

```
package com.wrox.projsp.ch03.myfirstwebapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/myfirstservlet")
public class MyFirstServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("This is my first servlet.");
    }
}
```

Compile and put the class file in: `webapps/ch03/WEB-INF/classes/com/wrox/projsp/ch03/myfirstwebapp/MyFirstServlet.class`

Restart tomcat, and access the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ch03/myfirstservlet`

Answer (score 0):

## Getting the result of a servlet in a browser:

***servlet:***

1. *Are created and managed at runtime by the Sun ONE Web Server servlet
   engine.*
2. *Operate on input data that is encapsulated in a request object*.
3. *Respond to a query with data encapsulated in a response object*.
4. *Are extensible*.
5. *Provide user session information persistence between interactions*.
6. *Can be dynamically reloaded while the server is running*.
7. *Are addressable with URLs. Buttons on an application's pages often
    point to servlets*.
8. *Can call other servlets and/or JSPs*.

***You should use this following method :***

```
`http://server:port/context_root/servlet/servlet_name?name=value`
```

***Explanation about the servlet:***

***server:port**> The IP address (or host name) and optional port number.*

***context-root**> The context path without the leading “/” at which the web application is installed.*

***servlet**> Only needed if no servlet-mapping is defined in the web.xml file.*

***servlet-name**> The servlet-name (or servlet-mapping if defined) as configured in the web.xml file.*

***?name=value**> Optional servlet name-value parameters.*

*you need to use the `ch03`(naming of the project) as url-pattern.. Try to access the file with the following `URL: http://localhost:8080/ch03/MyFirstServlet`*

*You need to configure your application properly in the `web.xml` file and if you want to use later a Java class and use it as a `Servlet` you have to define this in the `web.xml` like that:*

```
<servlet> 
   <servlet-name>MyFirstServlet</servlet-name> 
   <servlet-class>com.wrox.projsp.ch03.MyFirstServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>MyFirstServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/MyFirstServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*The url pattern defines the path you can access it later. To access the `MyFirstServlet` in the above code you need to use this `url: http://localhost:8080/MyFirstServlet`*

***Reference link:***

1. *http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/817-1833-10/pwasrvlt.html#wp34399*
2. *http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/817-1833-10/pwasrvlt.html#wp34478*

Comment: Do i need to have apache ant installed?Do i have to configure tomcat to port 80 instead of port 8080?What is it that i am doing wrong here ?